# QDockWidget::setWidget() calling QAbstractItemModel::rowCount on Windows but not on Linux

Tags: qt, qtreeview, rowcount, qdockwidget

Considering the following QAbstractItemModel subclass:

```
class MyItemModel : public QAbstractItemModel {
Q_OBJECT
public:
    (...)
    virtual int rowCount(const QModelIndex& parentIdx = QModelIndex()) const override;
    (...)
};
```

And a simple QDockWidget for displaying a QTreeView

```
class DockWidget : public QDockWidget {
Q_OBJECT
public:
    DockWidget() {
         view = new QTreeView();
         setWidget(view);
    }
private:
    QTreeView *view;
}
```

If I call DockWidget constructor on Windows **MyItemModel::rowCount()** is being called. If I use this code on Linux, **MyItemModel::rowCount()** isn't being called. Is this correct?

I suspect that Qt for Windows has something that trigger rowCount() when **QDockWidget::setWidget()** is called and this is not necessary on Linux. But it is just a guess.

> Qt version 4.8.3,
>   Windows 7 64 bits,
>   Ubuntu both 32 and 64bits